# Limit a Low Replace query to only the first instance

Tags: low-replace

Is there a way to limit the "find" and "Replace" to only the first occurance of an item?

For instance, I want to replace only the the first < p > tag with < p class="lead">

Thanks.
Russ

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though Low Replace can use [regex](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace/docs)  There's plenty of StackOverflow questions out there regarding regex first instance.